# How upvalues are counted in nested Lua functions?

Tags: lua

With a lua code chunk like this:

```
local a, b
function fA ()
    print(a)
    function fB ()
        print(b)
    end
end
```

How many upvalues fA exactly has, 1 or 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, all external local variables used in a function are counted as upvalues.
As already  mentioned, in Lua 5.2 there is also a hidden upvalue for the environment, if the function uses global variables.

You may want to read the bytecode generated for your code with `luac -l -l`.

What may have confused you is the definition of `fB` in the body of `fA`. Recall that 
`function fB () print(b) end` is just sugar for `fB = function () print(b) end`. When you do that, it is clear that `b` is being used in `fA` and also that you're assigning to a global variable `fB`. Hence you get 3 upvalues for `fA` in Lua 5.2. (The use of `print` also implies that `fA` uses global variables.) If you use `local function fB ...` and remove `print`, you'll see that `fA` uses 2 upvalues in both 5.1 and 5.2.

Answer (score 2):

It's implementation defined; it could be one or two. Or three (one upvalue for the environment). You don't know, and you should *never* have to care.